JOLT to check the value if it is null keep it as it is else update the value based on the condition
please provide the jolt spec for the following
JSON input :
[
  {
    "name": "Manu",
    "age": 26,
    "location": "New York",
    "risk": "0"
  },
  {
    "name": "Manju",
    "age": 29,
    "location": "New York city",
    "risk": null
  }
]

if risk is 0, then risklevel is Low
if risk is null, then risklevel is null
if risk is 1, then risklevel is High
[
  {
    "name": "Manu",
    "age": 26,
    "location": "New York",
    "risklevel": "Low"
  },
  {
    "name": "Manju",
    "age": 29,
    "location": "New York city",
    "risklevel": null
  }
]

Spec tried is :
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "name": "[&1].name",
        "age": "[&1].age",
        "location": "[&1].location",
        "risk": {
          "0": {
            "#Low": "[&2].risklevel"
          },
          "1": {
            "#High": "[&2].risklevel"
          },
          "null": null,
          "*": {
            "@(2,risklevel)": "[&2].risklevel"
          }
        },
        "*": "[&1].risklevel"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "risklevel": "null"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "risklevel": "=toString"
      }
    }
  }
]


You can use the following transformation :
[//set an arbtrary value(say "NUll") to a null valued "risk"
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "~risk": "NUll"//occures whnever risk is null due to the ~ operator 
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&1].&", //the attributes other than "risk"
        "risk": {
          "1": { "#High": "[&3].riskLevel" },//hardcode by # operator
          "0": { "#Low": "[&3].riskLevel" },
          "NUll": { "@": "[&3].riskLevel" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]


Refer
for the usage of ~ operator within a modify spec

the demo on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :


can someone help me in providing jolt spec for below question
